# multiple recipients in email in the webMail object?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, razor

How do you add multiple receipients, meaning more than one email in the TO: field using the webMatrix WebMail object?  I've messed around with creating a string that combines two emails with a comma or semicolon between them.

Comment: already tried to separate two email addresses with comma or semicolon or whatsoever and check how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do just that, separate multiple recipients in the 'to' property with a semicolon:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail.send(v=vs.99).aspx

Comment: I think this is the answer, but will have to research further at some distant time in the future.

Comment: Oddly, we've had commas work where semicolons failed.  Is it dependent on the SMTP on the server?